# Split string on the '.' dot characters that are not inside of [] brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, split

I have some string like:

```
"Item.ObjectA.ObjectBs[Id=1234;Name=Test;Date=12.05.2016 11:11:11].ObjectD.Value"
```

If I split it with `.` It gives:

> Item
>
> ObjectA
>
> ObjectBs[Id=1234;Name=Test;Date=12
>
> 05
>
> 2016 11:11:11]
>
> ObjectD
>
> Value

But I want a result, ignoring the dots inside `[]`, which is:

> Item
>
> ObjectA
>
> ObjectBs[Id=1234;Name=Test;Date=12.05.2016 11:11:11]
>
> ObjectD
>
> Value

How can i simply achieve this?

Comment: `\.(?![^[]*\])` would probably work - https://regex101.com/r/nI4cQ5/1

Comment: It worked with regex.split. Thanks!

Comment: if you need to escape the brackets:
`\.(?![^\[]*\])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Moving my comment to an answer:</sup>

One option is to use a negative lookahead in order to match `.` characters that are not followed by zero or more `[` characters and then a `]` character:

```
\.(?![^[]*\])
```

[**Live Example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DgMFPJ):

```
string pattern = @"\.(?![^[]*\])";
string input = "Item.ObjectA.ObjectBs[Id=1234;Name=Test;Date=12.05.2016 11:11:11].ObjectD.Value";

foreach (String split in Regex.Split(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(split);
}
```

Output:

> Item
>
> ObjectA
>
> ObjectBs[Id=1234;Name=Test;Date=12.05.2016 11:11:11]
>
> ObjectD
>
> Value

---

Alternatively, instead of splitting the string, you could also match based on the following expression:

```
[^.]*\[[^]]*\]|[^.]*
```

[**Live Example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N3VlvU):

```
string pattern = @"[^.]*\[[^]]*\]|[^.]*";
string input = "Item.ObjectA.ObjectBs[Id=1234;Name=Test;Date=12.05.2016 11:11:11].ObjectD.Value";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Same output.

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows how to do it in pure programming

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;                   
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        var orig = "Item.ObjectA.ObjectBs[Id=1234;Name=Test;Date=12.05.2016 11:11:11].ObjectD.Value";

        var parts = new List<string>();
        var stop = false;
        var current = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < orig.Length; i++)
        {

            if (orig[i] != '.')
                current.Append(orig[i]);

            if (orig[i] == '[')
                stop = true;

            if (orig[i] == ']')
                stop = false;

            if ((orig[i] == '.' && !stop) || i == orig.Length - 1)
            {
                parts.Add(current.ToString());
                current.Length = 0;
            }


        }

        parts.ForEach(x =>  Console.WriteLine(x));
    }
}
```

Result

`Item
ObjectA
ObjectBs[Id=1234;Name=Test;Date=12052016 11:11:11]
ObjectD
Value`